# Excel VBA 450 Tables.Add

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently learning VBA in Excel to produce Word documents from spreadsheet data.

I got error 450 : Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment.

I have no idea what's wrong. Can anyone help me?

Other than that, what should i do to insert string inside cell in table?

Thank you.

```
'Create document
Sub main()
Dim objWord As Object
Dim objDoc As Object
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
objWord.Visible = True
Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add()

Dim i As Integer
Dim strValue As String
For i = 1 To 5
    objDoc.Activate
    'define string
    strID = Cells(i, 1)
    strSTR = Cells(i, 2)
    strKK = Cells(i, 3)
    strDEF = Cells(i, 4)
    strEX = Cells(i, 5)
    'write the value to the document
    objWord.Selection.TypeText Text:=strID + ". " + strSTR + "  " + strKK + "  " + strDEF
    'move to the next line
    objWord.Selection.TypeParagraph
    objWord.Tables.Add Range:=Selection.Range, NumRows:=4, NumColumns:=3

Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
objDoc.Tables.Add Range:=objWord.Selection.Range, NumRows:=4, NumColumns:=3
```

That is use objDoc instead of objWord and use the objWord.Selection instead of just Selection

Comment: For me it adds a table.  It is badly visible because it doesn't have any borders.  Then it gets stuck in the first cell and adds an other table in that cell and so on.

To test this better I added this:


`Set myTable = objDoc.Tables.Add(Range:=objWord.Selection.Range, NumRows:=4,   NumColumns:=3)`
`myTable.Borders.Enable = True`
`myTable.Borders.InsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle`
`objDoc.Characters.Last.Select`
`objWord.Selection.Collapse`